How can the HTML5 required attribute fail to prevent form submission if a field is null?
On one of my forms, I have a text area with the required attribute
<textarea class="form-control" 
  id="text-area" name="text-area-name" 
  rows="1" placeholder="Enter some information..." required
  autocomplete="off"></textarea>

I have tested this form on my desktop, and android chrome browser. As expected if the field is null, the form will not submit and there is a message letting the user know, that they must fill it out.
Oddly, I checked my flask server logs this morning to find, that some user was trying to submit the form and this field was null. As such, the app would not put the information in the database because it is a required field.
So, as the questions states, how could a user have submitted this form without a value? What possible bug could I be looking for that allowed this to happen?

no, your textarea field is not null (empty) : there is a space character before the closing tagautocomplete="off"> </textarea> change this to autocomplete="off"></textarea>

Yes, this was only in the post. The html onsite there is no space. Additionally, a space submitted still wouldn't be null, it would be a string that contains a space.The user somehow submitted the form, and the value received in the flask route was null. My question is, how did the form even submit a null value since the required attribute is present.

I think there is an error in your code, but the little code you give does not allow to determine the causes of such a result. you must provide an example reproducing this problem.

Thank-you for the reply @MisterJojo. its a plain html form with various fields, I posted the field that returned the null value. When the form is posted, the value is fetched with form-field = request.form.get('form-field'). Then, it will attempt to save to the database if all fields were given.  My main pickle is, how could a user have successfully posted the form if a field was null when the required attribute was set.

This is impossible, there can be no sending if the elements with required attribute are not filled in. I have been making HTML form pages for years, and what you get can only happen if your HTML / javascript code is poorly designed.

@MisterJojo Thanks for confirming this, that's exactly what I wanted to verify. Upon further inspection, it appears that one of the scripts that fill this form on the users behalf had set the field to "null" which flask took literally and not as a string. I'm still not sure how that happened, but its a completely different question at this point.

Users can submit a null value even if they set the required attribute using their browser developer tools. If the user opens the browser's developer tools, removes required, and submits, a null value is submitted. It's very easy for users with knowledge of browser developer tools. To prevent this, you need to add validation logic on the backend side.
